# Prove inequality by induction: $0 \leq h(n) \leq n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N_0}$

Tags: inequality, induction, formal-languages

> $h: \mathbb{N_0} \rightarrow \mathbb{N_0}$ is defined as:
>
> $h(0) = 0 \\ \forall k \in \mathbb{N_+}: h(2k) = h(k) \\ \forall k \in \mathbb{N_0}: h(2k+1) = 1+ h(k)$
>
> a) Create a table with $n$ and $h(n)$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N_0}, n \leq 7$
>
> b) Prove by induction that $0 \leq h(n) \leq n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N_0}$
>
> Hint: Use strong induction.
>
> c) Which connection is between $w \in \{0,1\}^*$ and $h(Num_2(w))$

a)

- $n=0: h(n) = 0$
- $n=1: h(n) = 1$
- $n=2: h(n) = 1$
- $n=3: h(n) = 2$
- $n=4: h(n) = 1$
- $n=5: h(n) = 2$
- $n=6: h(n) = 2$
- $n=7: h(n) = 3$

b) Base case: $n=0: h(0) = 0 \Rightarrow 0 \leq h(0) \leq 0$

Inductive hypothesis:

$0 \leq h(n) \leq n$ holds true for some $n \in \mathbb{N_0}$

Inductive step:

$n \rightarrow n+1$, to show: $$$0 \leq h(n+1) \leq n+1$

1.case: $n$ is even, $n=2k$

$h(n+1) = h(2k +1)$ = 1+ h(k)

2.case: $n$ is odd, $n=2k +1$

$h(n+1) = h(2k +2) = h(2 \cdot (k+1)) = h(k+1)$

So in the first case when $n$ is even, it will go through all of the odd $n$.

In the second case when $n$ is odd, it will go through the even $n$.

This was the only idea I had but it doesn't seem to get me to the right direction.

How do I get to an inequality with $n + 1$?

Comment: for $n=2k$, $h(n+1)=1+h(k)\le1+k<1+n$; for $n=2k+1,h(n+1)=h(k+1)\le k+1<n+1$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner You should consider making your comment into an answer.

Comment: Note that $h(n)$ is the number of “ones” in the base-2 representation of $n$.

Comment: Strong Induction means, it holds for all numbers smaller than or equal to $n$...

Answer (score 1):

As [dmtri](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/482116/dmtri) commented on the question,

for [strong induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Complete_(strong)_induction), the inductive hypothesis would be that $0\le h(k)\le k$ **for all** $k\le n$.

With that, it is not difficult to show that $0\le h(n+1)\le n+1$ and complete the proof,

using the two cases you considered.

**Case 1.**    $n=2k.$

Then $h(n+1)=h(k)+1,$ and, by the inductive hypothesis, $0\le h(k)+1\le k+1<n+1$.

**Case 2.**     $n=2k+1.$

Then $h(n+1)=h(k+1)$, and, again using the inductive hypothesis,

$0\le h(k+1)\le k+1<n+1$.